# PHP scripts are being downloaded from localhost instead of displayed

Tags: apache2

When I view `http://localhost/` in Google Chrome, it tries to download the homepage as a file, and doesn't display it.  I tried `http://localhost/` in Firefox 4 and it works fine.

In Chrome though, loading `http://127.0.0.1` displays my website [which is PHP btw].

127.0.0.1 is `localhost` in my `/etc/hosts` file.

How can I make Chrome load my local website thru http://localhost?

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost/`?

Comment: Try opening http://localhost in a different browser, does it work then?

Comment: wow, weird.  Ok, so first off localhost loads `localhost/`, and I just tried Firefox, and it works. But not in Chrome.. edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually isn't anything *wrong* with the browser, per se. As I suspect, you created a php file - went to run it form the browser and it downloaded. So you went off, installed `php5` and `mod_php5` (and various other php packages) then tried again and it failed, again, but now `http://127.0.0.1` works! This is simply a caching issue. Chrome remembers that the last time it accessed that php file it was downloaded - so it'll keep doing that until the browsers cache is dumped.

Clear Chrome's cache and you should be good to go!

Comment: @Matt It's okay I've done this *a lot*