# Help with LAMP sever

Tags: 11.04, lamp

Firstly I followed the instructions on the following site to install the LAMP server:

http://www.multimediaboom.com/how-to-install-lamp-server-in-ubuntu-11-0410-1010-04/#comment-48391

step 3: go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin
This did not work. It came up with a 404 error at first then after running "sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www" it came up with a 403 error and said "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server".

Then the last step was to make a simple php file and test that php was working. I could not save the file into /var/www/

So to recap:

1. How do I get around the 403 forbidden error for phpmyadmin?
2. How do I save / copy / make files in /var/www/ when it is owned by root?

---

EDIT:

I have managed to save the test.php file into /var/www/ by launching gedit via the gksudo command. When I go to localhost/test.php however it downloads the test.php file instead of running it on the server.

---

Apache2 error log file contents:

```
[Tue Oct 04 15:30:27 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 04 15:30:30 2011] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Tue Oct 04 15:30:30 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 04 15:31:46 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 15:32:27 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Oct 04 15:32:27 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 15:33:17 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Oct 04 15:33:17 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:23 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:23 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:25 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:25 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:31 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:31 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:33 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:33 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:33 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:33 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:33 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:33 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 16:55:52 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 17:06:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Oct 04 17:06:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[    Tue Oct 04 17:24:34 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 17:24:42 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/php
[Tue Oct 04 17:24:42 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 17:25:42 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 17:25:42 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 18:31:45 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 04 19:07:40 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing apache2.conf or httpd.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Make sure you have there

```
include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

And that they are uncommented. I am not sure about the paths. 1st one will include phpmyadmin config file. 2nd will make phpmyadmin available on 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin. I'd have to see those config files. Try different things restarting apache on each change:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The directories need to be "executables" try a chmod 0755 /var/www

For php, you may need to do this :

```
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To answer your 2 questions

1. Checkout the /var/log/httpd/error.log
2. You write them with sudo or make a subdirectory with the appropriates permissions for your user

Worth reading :

ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Installing_PHP_5

Comment: chmod 0755 done no change. --
php said it was already enabled. --
apache restart failed. It could not find the apache.conf file. --
1. there was no httpd folder -- 2. figured out how to write to the directory thanks.

Comment: Sorry it is /var/log/apache2/, look for the error log to know why you receive theses errors. If you are still unsure, paste them here.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to php as well as linux so I posted the error file contents above.

Comment: I read the link you posted above. it said "If this doesn't work, then it is a problem of file authorisation". Not quite sure what that means. I dont know if I did the chmod correctly though. Do you think I could have step by step instructions for the chmod? Cheers.

Comment: "chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www': Operation not permitted" How do I change the permissions for this directory? I put a sudo in front of it but I dont think that works (as nothing happened).

Comment: ok I finally realized you could do it with "sudo su" although it did not help at all. It still downloads the file instead of sending it to php.

Comment: @cohen For "still downloads the file" please make sure [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61284/php-scripts-are-being-downloaded-from-localhost-instead-of-displayed/61303#61303) isn't the issue.

Comment: Hi, nothing will happen as the permissions are now set (yes you need sudo if your not the owner of the directory). You can check that /var/www is in 755 by doing ls -l /var/   you should see next to www:  drwxr-xr-x www

Comment: Checked your edit :  Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/phpmyadmin. For phpmyadmin under the lamp stack, you should read this : http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/phpmyadmin  espacialy if you don't know about directory permissions under apache, this can be a hard learning curve just to get phpmyadmin to work. But if you want to know about it, this is the FollowSymLinks option.

Comment: Reconfigure the package phpmyadmin
Open a terminal, type

sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
and be sure to select the version of your server HTTP (apache2 normally). When I put that in, it says: "sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
Package `phpmyadmin' is not installed and no info is available.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: phpmyadmin is not installed"

Comment: do this : sudo apt-get --purge remove phpmyadmin ; sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin ; sudo a2ensite phpmyadmin