# How can I write to /var/www?

Tags: installation, permissions, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the simplest way to add files to “/var/www”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-add-files-to-var-www)

Ok, I am trying to set up LAMP.  Do a test run to make sure everything is working.  I have no idea what permissions, Apache, PHP, SQL.  Clueless.
I am following these instructions:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Now, when I get down to testing PHP.  It tells me to create that simple file and store it into the www directory.  I can't.  I opened a notepad editor, wrote the file, went to save it as the directory and it tells me I do not have permission to save the file.  I don't know who has permissions?  Me?  My Apache user?  I don't have a clue.  The tutorial just assumes one knows how to set permissions.  How do I do this?
I apologize if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find it.  This is the closest I've came to an answer:
[Help with LAMP sever](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64183/help-with-lamp-sever)

I just need a "Just type this into terminal - " Type of answer.  I don't care about permissions, it is a closed machine and just used for testing...