# Phpmyadmin isn't working?

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

<s>I installed Apache2 and PHP with success, but when I want visit `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` I got the following error:</s>

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

How can I fix this, because I need it working before I can continue.

---

**Edit:**
Now I have a new error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: I tried that solution, but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: Does localhost work? That is, a simple php file in localhost?

Comment: http://www.imgdumper.nl/uploads7/538b5e3a2520f/538b5e3a16fa3-Schermafdruk_van_2014-06-01_19:08:53.png

Comment: You're running 14.04 right? If so, try running this command: `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: That's simple to fix - see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www) though for your case it will be `/var/www/html`

Comment: Still the 403 error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14854/discussion-between-parto-and-korkel).

Comment: Does [Forbidden :You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235363/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-server) (on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)) help with this? There's also [Help with LAMP sever](http://askubuntu.com/q/64183/22949) here on Ask Ubuntu, which might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y
```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin -y
```

Now I can access `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

Answer (score 4):

If you used the command...

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server
```

phpMyAdmin will not automatically install.

You need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

And for future reference, I install lamp servers using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin
```

Comment: I tried that already, but not helping.

Comment: Is phpmyadmin.conf in /etc/apache2/conf-available?

this might be a dumb question.. but when you go to http://localhost/ does anything come up?

Comment: In Localhost yes, I added already something. How do I chek?

Comment: sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin            command  solved my problem.